# Loading a Fragment is taking more time in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask

I am trying to replace a fragment in Android and its taking almost 2-3 seconds to load the fragment into the UI. I am not sure what might be causing the issue because I don't do perform heavy threads in the `onCreateView`.

My fragment that is taking too much time to load has the following in its `onCreateView`.

Link : [Code for my onCreateView](http://pastebin.com/L2497bEZ)

All I do in my onCreateView is play around with the visibility of certain layouts depending upon the data from DB. I don't think that it would take me so much time to load the page, it doesn't make sense to me.

**What have I tried so far :**

I haven't tried anything solid except the following which are some silly implementations of stupidity or I think so..

1. Tried to place a major chunk of code in an Async Task but as most of the code requires `setVisibility()`, it doesn't work in `doInBackground()`. And adding a `runOnUIThread()` is again same as not using a Async Task.
2. I doubted that the fragment manager might be taking some time to load the fragment into UI but when I replaced with another fragment with lesser UI components then it seemed to load fast.I also tried using `getFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();`.

So thats what I have tried so far but also found out that option 2 is completely unnecessary because the log that I print before the `return convertView;` is taking 1-2 seconds to print. I am not sure what is going wrong or where its going wrong. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Access to your google doc is restricted.

Comment: Oops, sorry.. My bad, will correct it now.

Comment: It is the longest `onCreateView` I've ever seen. So I'm almost sure that the problem is in complexity. It's hard to read your code in google docs, so I can't say what to change in your code to improve performance, but at least you need to decrease amount of views, and decrease manual usage of `LayoutParams`. Also I would recommend you to publish image of your UI.

Comment: Point taken, will publish the UI shortly.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't have to call `super.onCreate()` in `onCreateView`. Secondly, you are doing `too much DB operations in oncreateView` by instructions like `dbHelper.getRelationGenderForEdit` etc. You have to perform these operations in the `backGroundThread`. You can use `Loaders` or `AsyncTasks` to achieve this and pass these results to `Fragment` and use those values in `onCreateView`

Hope this helps.

Comment: But all the visibility factors depend upon the result from the DB, if I use a AsyncTask for DB operations then there will be too much of back and forth operations. Wont that be the case ?

Comment: First of all: you should create a loading screen and start the background task for your database stuff. One task, fetch all you need there, create a custom pojo that contains all data you need to decide about layout stuff. When delivering the result, update your layout and dismiss the loading screen. done (advanced tips like "prefetching" etc are also possible but start with a simple solution first)

Comment: Before initiating the `Fragment`, do your work in the background and intimate the user about your processing,or you can also save your data on application launch so that you don't have to fetch again and again. You only update the value when DB Value change. When you have that data on application launch, then your `Fragment` will load  smoothly